# Possible to get javascript object to return value instead of self?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

So I have this:

```
var setting = function (val,desc) {
    this.val = val;
    this.desc = desc;
};

var option = new setting(15,"This is a setting");
```

and I was wondering if I could get `option` to return `value` rather than the object.

I tried adding this to `setting`

```
var setting = function (val,desc) {
    this.val = vall;
    this.desc = desc;
    return this.val;
};
```

But it didn't work. Is it even possible? I'd like the `option` to return `val`, but still have `option.val` return `val` and `option.desc` to return `desc`.

Comment: `this.val = val ? val : null` is the same as `this.val = val || null` which can be just `this.val = val` in your context, since `null == undefined`

Comment: ...good point, editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the `toString` method manually to overwrite what happens when the object is treated like a string.

Do note that although it will allow you to treat the object like a string, you cant rely on it acting like one in all situations, especially in situations where you can normally use string functions. (things like `.split` etc. will not work unless you define them manually)

Comment: I tried adding `this.prototype.toString = function(){ return this.val }` but it didn't work.

Comment: @DaltonGore just `this.toString` no need for the `prototype`

Comment: I just tried it here, and it doesn't appear to be working:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rQMv4/)

Comment: @DaltonGore `console.log` is one of those exceptions I mentioned, try `alert` instead and it will work

Answer (score 2):

```
var option = (new setting(15,"This is a setting")).val;
```

is that enough?

Comment: Wouldn't that just assing option to 15, though?

Answer (score 1):

If a constructor function returns nothing, null, or any atomic / non-object value then said value is ignored and the newly created object reference is given back to the caller.
so...

```
var setting = function (val,desc) {
    this.val = val ? val : null;
    this.desc = desc ? desc : null;
    return {val : this.val}
};
```